# Node.JS async function running forever no result

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, callback

I am new to async / await and promises and such in JS. I am trying to build a small bit of software which actually seems to work. However, one function doesn't finish and seems to run forever without returning a result. Here is my code:

```
module.exports.visit = (val) => {

        let visit_date = Date.now();
        let data_json;
        let insert;

        client.get(val)
        .then( (data) => {
                data_json = JSON.parse(data);
                data_json.count += 1;
                data_json.last_visited = visit_date;
                insert  = JSON.stringify(data_json);
                client.set(val,insert);
                console.log(insert);
                return data_json.url;
        })
        .catch((err) => {
                console.log(err);
        });
}
```

The function calling this function (in order to return the url):

```
async function visitor() {
        // also doesn't work with let a = await helpers.visit('6q9ootm8p7');
        let a = helpers.visit('6q9ootm8p7');
        return a;
        }

visitor();
```

I would be very thankful if somebody could point me into the same direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`helpers.visit` must return a promise. Currently, it is void. Try:

```js
return client.get(val)
  .then(() => {
    // provide your code here, and return the data
    return ... ;
  })
  .catch(error => {
    console.error(error);

    // if you catch an error, you should provide your result data too
    return ... ;
  })
;
```